# OutOfMemoryException occurred when uploading file using Symfony

Tags: symfony, file-upload

I have followed the instructions in the Symfony documentation for how to upload a file exactly as per https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html.

However when I post the file using Postman I get an OutOfMemoryException. Does anyone know what causes this and how to fix it?

The error received is as follows:
(1/1) OutOfMemoryException
Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 109056000 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini change configuration

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

also, check

```
post_max_size = 8M
```

change this configuration ...
restart server and check